Creating a geom_line plot where as the numeric value on x-axis increased, the y-axis shows a cumulative count
I have the following data set:
df <- data.frame(
  Passwords = c("123er", "234f4", "234r4", "234f6", "234f8","274f4","294f4",
                "204f4","23yf4","2l4f4","2u4f4","23of4","734f4","834f4",
                "934f4","234w4","267f4"),
  Days_Elapsed = c(1,1,1,4,4,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9))


The objective is to create a geom-line plot that shows an ever upwards line corresponding to the number of passwords registered as the Days-Elapsed variable increases. For example, when Days_Elapsed equals 1, there are three passwords, meaning that, in the plot, on the x-axis value for 1, there would be a y-value of 3. This value of 3 would remain consistent for Days_Elapsed 2 and 3, as no passwords were registered on these days (meaning the line would be perfectly horizontal). This line would then increase to 5 as the Days-Elapsed reach the value of 4 (because two more passwords were registered on day 4). On day 5 there are three more passwords, so the line in Y would increase to the value 8, and so on.
I reckon this is fairly simple but I just cannot find a way to get it done. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

it seems the function you were looking for is geom_step() in ggplot2. But to use it you must transform your data a bit:

To get the count of passwords by days elapsed
To get the cumulative number of days

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  Passwords = c("123er", "234f4", "234r4", "234f6", "234f8","274f4","294f4",
                "204f4","23yf4","2l4f4","2u4f4","23of4","734f4","834f4",
                "934f4","234w4","267f4"),
  Days_Elapsed = c(1,1,1,4,4,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9))

df |> count(Days_Elapsed) |> # for 1.
  mutate(
    n_cumul = cumsum(n) # for 2.
  ) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = Days_Elapsed, y = n_cumul )) +
  geom_step()


Hope that helps ; )

You might want to look at lubridate to convert your numeric days into proper period for a better display by ggplot2 ;)

Nice. Much better than my geom_line and does not require to complete the dataset.

Thanks @stefan, but I learned about the full_seq function now ;)

@stefan
If the passwords that are being summed on the Y-axis can be broken down according to a factor titled "Company" with "Company1" and "Company2" would it still be feasible to implement this code? I ask because I tried to add group = Company to aes and it did not work, nor did the colour = Company, as it says there is no object title Company. I assume this has to do with the wrangling?

@StatsIliterate Try with ... count(Company, Days_Elapsed) |> mutate(n = cumsum(n), .by = Company) ... to compute the (cumulative) counts by day and company.

Works brilliantly @stefan, thank you for all your help!!

Here is a one-liner, using data.table. The reason this works is because .I does not respect grouping (which is sometimes annoying, but in this case, useful).
library(data.table)

ggplot(setDT(df)[, n:=max(.I), Days_Elapsed], aes(Days_Elapsed, r)) + geom_step()

Output:


Here is one approach to achieve your desired result which requires some data wrangling using dplyr and tidyr:
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df |>
  count(Days_Elapsed) |>
  tidyr::complete(
    Days_Elapsed = tidyr::full_seq(Days_Elapsed, 1),
    fill = list(n = 0)
  ) |>
  mutate(
    n = cumsum(n)
  ) |>
  ggplot(aes(Days_Elapsed, n)) +
  geom_line()



@StatsIliterate Personally I would suggest to accept the other answer as IMHO it provides a more elegant and easier approach.
